# Entity Framework Conceptual Clarification

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first, circular-reference

***This question is purely conceptual!*** *The code below works fine, but I can't figure out how . . .*

---

### The Scenario

I've begun reading up on Entity Framework concepts, and I'm currently using the information and examples located [**here**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2010/06/21/productivity-improvements-for-the-entity-framework.aspx) to build my first MVC project. Here's the code example from that link:

```
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
    Imports System.Data.Entity

    Namespace MyDataAccessDemo

        Module Program

            Sub Main()

                Using context As New ProductContext()

                    Dim food As New Category With {.CategoryId = "FOOD"}
                    context.Categories.Add(food)

                    Dim cheese As New Product With {.Name = "Cheese"}
                    cheese.Category = context.Categories.Find("FOOD") 

                    context.Products.Add(cheese)
                    context.SaveChanges()
                End Using

            End Sub

        End Module

        Public Class ProductContext : Inherits DbContext

            Public Property Products As DbSet(Of Product)
            Public Property Categories As DbSet(Of Category)

        End Class


        Public Class Product

            Public Property ProductId As Integer
            Public Property Name As String
            Public Property Category As Category ' <-- Circular reference?

        End Class

        Public Class Category

            Public Property CategoryId As String
            Public Property Name As String
            Public Property Products As ICollection(Of Product) ' <-- Circular reference?

        End Class
    End Namespace
```

---

### The Problem

So, "Category" is a class and "Product" is a class. **Category** contains a collection of its **products**, each **product** of which contains its **category**, which contains a collection of its **products**, each **product** of which contains its **category**, which contains a collection of **products** . . . well, you get the idea.

---

### The Question

Why does this work? Shouldn't this cause some kind of circular reference? I would think the category would contain the product IDs and vice versa, not the objects themselves.

Comment: Those are called [Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Awesome! I've been looking for that article. :) Re-post that as an answer and I will mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are called Navigation Properties, you can find out more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) on the Entity framework website.